# Filtering a group by linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

```
 var testingAll =          (from ac in metaData.AcTable
                            where ac.Call >= DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-2) && ac.Call  <= DateTime.Now 
                            group adminCall by ac.LanguageCode into acc
                            select new { lang = acc.Key, count = acc.Count() }).ToDictionary(x => x.lang, y => y.count).OrderByDescending(x => x.Key);
```

Can I have filter again after the datetime ?

Something like this:

```
var Today = testingAll.Where( /*x => x.Call >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2)*/)
```

Comment: Why not try it out?

Comment: From what I can tell you only have a `Dictionary` object which contains `lang` and `count`, so the `Call` values don't exist anymore... so the answer would be no

Comment: I don't believe you can, which you just export the `Key` and `Count`.  And why you don't put that filter in first `linq`?

Comment: I do want something like: make a general query, for Db, and after that only filter it as many times as I want

Comment: is the call property datetime?

Comment: no you cant as the time property is lost

Comment: Then maybe you should save result without grouping and don't transform it to dictionary, so that you can access the `Call` and filter it later

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like

```
var testingAll =          (from ac in metaData.AcTable
                            where ac.Call >= DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-2) && ac.Call  <= DateTime.Now 
                            group adminCall by adminCall.LanguageCode into ac
                            select ac
```

this should give back a collection where you can then query a number of times.

Comment: can you give me a simple example on how to filter your example with a Where clause?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you *can't* do this. Think of it this way, the problem is effectively the same as me giving you the average age of children in a class and then you taking that number and trying to work out the average age of the boys only - it's not possible without the source data.

Now you could *maybe* do this by building an expression and spending a lot of effort there, but it would still have to re-query the database.

If you really want to abstract it away slightly, then you could create a function that takes the where predicate as a parameter:

```
public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, int>> GetFilteredCalls(
    Expression<Func<Call, bool>> predicate)
{
    return calls
        .Where(predicate)
        .GroupBy(c => c.LanguageCode)
        .Select(g => new { Lang = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Lang, y => y.Count)
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Key);
}
```

And you use it like this:

```
var calls = GetFilteredCalls(c => c.Call >= DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-2) 
                                  && c.Call <= DateTime.Now);

var moreCalls = GetFilteredCalls(c => c.Call >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2) 
                                  && c.Call <= DateTime.Now);
```